# Recognizing patterns across columns and totaling up scores

Tags: r, count, sum

I'm hoping to detect specific patterns of 2s across columns, providing a total out of 2, for how many each student (Ids) got correct out of 2 questions.

Students were asked to state which of 6 travel techniques (Chute, Lee, Early, Wait48, Solar & Conn) is highly applicable in each of 5 weather scenarios.

The correct answers are:
Storm-Wait48, Wind-Lee, Persistent-Conn, Wet-Early & Solar, Ldry-Chute

If students correctly identified the highly applicable strategy (shown by the number 2) in accordance with the key stated above, they should get 1 point. If they did this in both scenarios they should get 2 points.

```
# Note: the numbers relate to the student's selected responses as follows:
# 0= Not applicable, 1= Somewhat Applicable, 2= Highly applicable, NA = 
Don't know
WeatherScen1 <- c('storm', 'persistent', 'wet', 'wet', 'storm', 'wind', 
'Ldry')
Solar1 <- c(0, 1, 2, 0, 0, NA, 2)
Conn1 <- c(1, 2, 0, 2, 0, NA, 1)
Chute1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, NA, 1)
Early1 <- c(0, 1, 2, 1, 1, NA, 2)
Wait481 <- c(2, 0, 0, 2, 1, NA, 2)
Lee1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1)
WeatherScen2 <- c('wet', 'wet', 'wind', 'storm', 'Ldry', 'storm', 
'persistent')
Solar2 <- c(2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
Conn2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2)
Chute2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
Early2 <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
Wait482 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0)
Lee2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0)

WeatherScenResp <- data.frame(WeatherScen1, Solar1, Conn1, Chute1, Early1, 
Wait481, Lee1, WeatherScen2, Solar2, Conn2, Chute2, Early2, Wait482, Lee2)
View(WeatherScenResp)

Id WeatherScen1 Solar1 Conn1 Chute1 Early1 Wait481 Lee1... 
1  Storm        0      1     1      0      2       1   ... 
2  Persistent   1      2     1      1      0       1   ... 
3  Wet          2      0     1      2      0       1   ...
4  Wet          0      2     2      1      2       0   ... 
5  Storm        0      0     2      1      1       1   ... 
6  Wind         NA     NA    NA     NA     NA      NA  ... 
7  Ldry         2      1     1      2      2       1   ... 


...WeatherScen2 Solar2 Conn2 Chute2 Early2 Wait482 Lee2
...Wet          2      0     1      2      0       1
...Wet          2      0     1      2      0       1
...Wind         0      1     1      1      1       2
...Storm        0      1     1      1      1       1
...Ldry         0      0     1      1      1       1
...Storm        1      1     1      1      2       1
...Persistent   0      2     1      0      0       0
```

How can I create an additional column called something like 'TotalCorrect' that would display 2 points for students 1 2 & 3, 0 points for students 4 & 5 and 1 point for students 6 & 7?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: im confused, where is the student data? how do we know what each student picked?

Comment: Hi @RAB, each of the rows/Ids represents a student.

Comment: Their picks are represented by the NA/0/1/2 displayed in each cell. # 0= Not applicable, 1= Somewhat Applicable, 2= Highly applicable, NA = Don't know. I'm only interested in counting whether they correctly picked their 2s. So, if a student was randomly assigned wet, they should have a 2 in Solar and Early, and if they were randomly assigned Ldry, they should have a 2 in Chute.

Answer (score 1):

Using data I made up I can show you the principles:

```
# create dataframe
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:7, A1 = sample(0:2, 7, T), A2 = sample(0:2, 7, T))

#  ID A1 A2
#1  1  1  0
#2  2  0  2
#3  3  2  1
#4  4  2  0
#5  5  2  0
#6  6  1  2
#7  7  2  1
```

Now iterate over each row and count the number of 2s (except the first column)

```
df$Count_2 <- apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) length(x[x==2]))
```

This will go through each row and get the exact number of 2s. You can then divide this column by 2 to get the point value, as each 2 pointer is worth 1 point:

```
df$points <- df$Count_2/2
```

Does this do what you're after?

**Edit:**

As akrun pointed out in the comments, `rowMeans(df[-1] == 2)` is a better way to do than the apply function.

Comment: Perhaps you are after `rowMeans(df[-1] == 2)`

Comment: yeah, that would be way better

Comment: Hi RAB and akrun, thanks very much for your help with this. I like both the methods that you suggested. However, I'm not hoping to sum the number of 2s in each row. For each weather scenario, the 2s have to be in specific columns. Ie in the WeatherScen of Persistent, they should have a 2 specifically in the column 'Conn'. If they were given the weather scenario of wet, they should have two 2s, one in the column Solar and another in the column Early (this would only be one point for Wet though)

Comment: i thought the 2 was assigned if they correctly guessed that combo? I am very confused.. :P

Comment: It certainly isn't a straightforward example... I'll have another crack at explaining it.The 2s represent the instances in which they said each travel technique (Early, Chute, Lee...) was highly applicable for managing each weather scenario (Storm, Wet, Wind...). Some of the students selected 2s in the correct instances (e.g. students 1,2 & 3) however some students selected highly applicable/2 incorrectly (e.g. students 4 & 5). So in my count column, I'm hoping to give points to some combinations of 2s and not others

Comment: just use a nested for-loop and hard code the answers to look for. this type of problem is unlikely to have a generic or neat answer